# In this case, why is the intersection of U = ∅?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook states the following example when studying families of sets, but I can't quite understand it. Let $U = \{(0, 1/n), \text{ where }n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$. It is therefore true that the intersection of $U = \emptyset$.

I've attempted a direct proof of this, but what I've written doesn't make much sense. It's clear to me that $n \in {\Bbb N}$, and that $U$ has elements of the form $A_1 = (0, 1)$, $A_2 = (0, 1/2)$, $A_3 = (0, 1/3)$, but I don't understand how we can prove with that given information that the intersection of $U = \emptyset$. How could I tackle this proof?

Comment: Given any real $r$, if $r\leq 0$, then it is isn’t in any of the intervals. If $r\gt 1$, then it isn’t in any of the intervals. And if $0\lt r\leq 1$, you just need to find a single one of the intervals that does not contain $r$ to show $r$ is not in the intersection. And you prove that?

Comment: Clearly $0$ and any negative $x$ is not in any interval $(0,1/n)$; can you show that for any positive $x$ there is some interval $(0,1/n)$ not containing $x$, so no positive $x$ is in the intersection of all those intervals either?

Answer (score 1):

For infinite intersection use Archimedean property.

Answer (score 1):

Try a proof by contradiction, and as stated above, use the archimedian property, that is: $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$. (I'll include the proof, so if you're trying to do it by yourself, be careful to not read my full answer).

Now, I´ll state a useful lemma (however, I won't prove it here, but it is quite simple): if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that, if for any given $\varepsilon>0$ then $|x|<\varepsilon$, then $x=0$.

Now, for your problem, let's assume that its intersection is non-empty, that is, there is an $x^*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any natural number $n$, $x\in(0,1/n)$, i.e., $0<x^*<1/n$. Now, let $\varepsilon >0$. Because of the Archimedian property, there exists an $N^*\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies $1/\varepsilon<N^*$, which implies $1/N^*<\varepsilon$. Now, because $N^*\in\mathbb{N}$, due to what we are assuming, $x^*<1/N^*<\varepsilon$, and we are also assuming that $0<x^*$, so $|x^*|=x^*$. We can now conclude that $|x^*|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ then $|x^*|<\varepsilon$, and according to the lemma, $x^*=0$, a contradiction. This concludes that its intersection is indeed empty.

Comment: This is a neat idea and the method (proof by contradiction) makes the most sense to me, but at the same time I’ve yet to come across the Archimedean property in my course. Is there a way to prove this without using said property?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I’m afraid it’s not the case. I can think of something, but it is a result that is actually equivalent to the Archimedean property. Have you proven the fact that the sequence (1/n) converges to 0 as n goes to infinity? If so (but I doubt it because you haven’t seen the property) you could give a similar argument using that fact.